# Who are those heroes and gods in Justice League?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, justice-league-2017

In that scene where Steppenwolf is trying to conquer the Earth for the first time, there are heroes and gods united to face him (Atlantis, Amazons and human).

Does anyone know which heroes and gods are on that battle?
I guess that I saw Zeus and Artemis, but there are more.

Comment: Related - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82796/what-were-all-the-fighters-in-previous-age-of-heroes

Comment: ..and https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82858/are-there-additional-hints-of-green-lantern

Comment: Thanks, i forgot about the green lantern

Comment: @LucioZenir - I removed the edit as it appeared to be an attempt to answer (at least in part) your own question. If it was, I recommend you post it as an answer below. If it was not, I apologize and you can rollback or re [edit]. If you did intend it to be part of the question, it was not obvious at all and could use some clarification should you add it in again.

Answer (score 1):

In order of appearance.

### Alien Green Lantern

[image]

### Artemis

[image]

### Zeus

[image]

### Minotaur? probably

[image]

### Ares (seen taking off his helmet, right of Zeus), Menalippe, Antiope, and Hippolyta

[image]